# Using one class in multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Okay so I have a class that I would like to create two objects that are in two separate projects. I have tried referencing the two other namespaces and adding the `using ...` to my code, but something is not working. For some reason one of the two works, but the other doesn't. I can create objects of one type but the other still wont let me, even though I am referencing them the same and calling them the same way. Is there some rule where I can only use one namespace? How can I create objects of both types?

Comment: can you share your code, without code nobody will be able to help you.. and noone is going to write code for your project...

Comment: It's not clear from your narrative what you're trying to do. An [MCVE] would help immensely. It would probably start with "create three class libraries in VS, then post these three classes into those three projects, and have project three reference the other two..."

Comment: Check both classes and make sure that they are both **public**.

Answer (score 1):

To create object of a class you need to provide reference to the namespace which has the required class.

For example

```
namespace My.Namespace1
{
    public class MyClassA
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            // Use value from MyOtherClass
            int myValue = My.Other.Namespace.MyOtherClass.MyInt;
        }
    }
}

namespace My.Other.Namespace1
{
    public class MyOtherClass
    {
        private static int myInt;
        public static int MyInt
        {
            get {return myInt;}
            set {myInt = value;}
        }


        public static int MyOtherInt {get;set;}
    }
}
```